# Babel seems to ignore NODE_ENV

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

According to the docs Babel will use NODE_ENV to set env specific options if BABEL_ENV is not specified. I noticed today that this doesn't work, or at least on my machine.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "babel-exp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start1": "NODE_ENV=foo babel-node src/index",
    "start2": "BABEL_ENV=foo babel-node src/index"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "env": {
    "foo": {
      "presets": ["env"]
    }
  }
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
import { hello, bye } from './sayings'

console.log('hello = ', hello);
```

**src/sayings.js**

```
export const hello = 'hello'
export const bye = 'bye'
```

Running start1 with either npm or yarn results in: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`
start2 logs `hello =  hello` correctly

node: v7.10.0
yarn: v0.24.6
npm: 4.1.1

I suppose the folks at Babel didn't change this behaviour, so it's probably something I am doing wrong. I would be happy if someone can verify this problem, or provide any other feedback.

Comment: Both work fine if no `BABEL_ENV` has been set. Did you maybe define the shell variable before? Does `echo $BABEL_ENV` show anything? If so you can try to unset it with: `unset BABEL_ENV`

Comment: Thanks for responding! `echo $BABEL_ENV` returns a blank line, so it's not that. I was afraid this is something particular to my machine, I have a suspicion that somehow my Node installation is messed up.

Comment: mmh, I am so used working with Atom and it's shell, that I didn't even try it in Terminal. Both work there too. At least I have something to go on now. Thanks again @Michael Jungo